# Pyppeteer: error when clicking on link with href "javascript:void(0);"

Tags: python, html, pyppeteer

A beginner in JS/Html, I'm trying to click on a link in an unordered list, through Pyppeteer0.2.5 (Python3.6.9/Chromium 87.0.4280.66). The html code of the link is:

```
<li class="ml2 sel"><a class="click sel clicked" href="javascript:void(0);" url="qosSettings.htm"><span class="text T">Settings</span></a></li>
```

My pyppeteer code is:

```
await page.click('[class="click sel clicked"]')
```

But I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 77, in <module>
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 484, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "test.py", line 55, in main
    await go_to_qos_settings(page)
  File "test.py", line 26, in go_to_qos_settings
    await page.click(btn)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/page.py", line 1546, in click
    await frame.click(selector, options, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/frame_manager.py", line 581, in click
    handle = await self.J(selector)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/frame_manager.py", line 317, in querySelector
    value = await document.querySelector(selector)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/element_handle.py", line 360, in querySelector
    self, selector,
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/execution_context.py", line 113, in evaluateHandle
    helper.getExceptionMessage(exceptionDetails)))
pyppeteer.errors.ElementHandleError: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'javascript:void(0);' is not a valid selector.
    at __pyppeteer_evaluation_script__:1:33
```

Any idea how to click on a link whose href is `javascript:void(0);`? From what I've read this can sometimes be replaced by an `onclick` method but no such thing appears in the html code.